# get already created mysqliDb connection from another class

Tags: php, mysql, class, php-mysqlidb

I have MysqliDb https://github.com/joshcam/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class.

In my php class:

```
<?php 
require_once ('MysqliDb.php');

class Main{

protected $db;   


public function __construct()
{
    $this->db = new MysqliDb ('localhost', 'root', 'tuncay', 'db');
}

}

Class A extends Main{

public function __construct()
{   
    $this->db = MysqliDb::getInstance();
    echo $this->db->where("id", 5)->getOne('test')['text'];
}

}

$a = new A();

?>
```

> **Fatal error: Call to a member function where() on null in /.../db/index.php on line 21**
>   *where() function belongs MysqliDb.php*

What is wrong? I got $this->db from Main class

**I just want to keep DB connection in A class and use it.**

Comment: hmm... if you haven't instatiated class Main before, then there's no DB connection to keep!? Maybe you want to do `parent::_construct()`?

Answer (score 3):

Your Class A replace parent __construct. Try add

```
Class A extends Main{
  public function __construct()
  {   
     parent::__construct();
     $this->db = MysqliDb::getInstance();
     echo $this->db->where("id", 5)->getOne('test')['text'];
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: this line `$this->db = MysqliDb::getInstance();` doesn't make sense then, or is not needed.

Comment: In A class I just want to use $this->db which is in Main class. If I use parent::_construct then connection will be repeated again. Is it normal?

Comment: now your child construct just replace your parent construct and   `$this->db = new MysqliDb ('localhost', 'root', 'tuncay', 'db');` dont uses. If your add `parent::__construct()` it will be uses.

Comment: what about memory?? each time calling the same function parent::_constract or connectDB ... or every time memory the same?

Answer (score 1):

Then you mean I can do like this:

```
<?php 
require_once ('MysqliDb.php');

class Main{

  protected  $db;   

   public function connectDB()
   {
    $this->db = new MysqliDb ('localhost', 'root', 'pass', 'db');
   }
}

Class A extends Main{
   public function __construct()
   {   
    $this->connectDB();
    echo $this->db->where("id", 5)->getOne('test')['text'];
   }
}

$a = new A();
?>
```

**Is this normal?** I mean, each time calling connectDB() function won't damage memory? or it will call every time the same part of memory ...?